# Смена изображения при наведении на ссылку

Tags: javascript, html, css

Здравствуйте, подскажите не сложное решение смены изображений при наведении на ссылку, спасибо заранее.

```
<div class="images">
    блок в котором происходит смена изображений
    <img src="../img/1.jpg">
</div>

`<a href="#">`Ссылка при наведении на которую происходит смени изображений в блоке изображений</a>
```

Comment: чтобы добавить код, выделите его мышкой в редакторе и нажмите вверху на `{ }` либо нажмите на клавиатуре Ctrl+K

Comment: @lexxl там уже правка с кодом скоро должна появиться

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var link = document.querySelector('a'),
    image = document.querySelector('img'),
    source = image.src;
link.onmouseenter = function() {
  image.src = 'http://s1.iconbird.com/ico/2013/12/524/w128h1281387196845secretsmile.png';
}
link.onmouseleave = function() {
  image.src = source;
}
```

```html
<div class="images">
    блок в котором происходит смена изображений
    <img src="http://www.iconsearch.ru/uploads/icons/lin/128x128/4.png">
</div>

<a href="#">Ссылка при наведении на которую происходит смени изображений в блоке изображений</a>
```

Comment: Спасибо похоже то что нужно, попробую натянуть на smarty

Answer (score 0):

Если есть возможность поменять порядок блока с картинками и ссылку, то вот:

```css
.images-holder img:first-child {
  display: none;
}
a:hover + .images .images-holder img:first-child {
  display: block;
}
a:hover + .images .images-holder img:last-child {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Ссылка при наведении на которую происходит смени изображений в блоке изображений</a>
<div class="images">
  блок в котором происходит смена изображений
  <div class="images-holder">
    <img src="https://www.google.ru/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png">
    <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-ui-set/154/y-letter-yandex-search-sign-emblem-128.png">
  </div>
</div>
```